# best way to create feature field for a product in Django

Tags: django, django-models

a Mobile device has many features in different types.

RAM=4: int

fingerprint=yes : boolean

camera=face detection, touch focus, panorama ...

how to create field for features, create an app for features and declare each feature type ? :

```
class IntFeature(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    value = models.IntegerField()


class BoolFeature(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    value = models.BooleanField()


class CharFeature(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    value = models.CharField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess all you need is just one class with an extra field which you'll define the type that you'll refer to it to cast the value

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    value = models.CharField()  # it should be a string
    type  = models.CharField()  # it could be an object, array, json, int, boolean ..
```

#### UPDATE

it seems you want to assign a bunch of `attributes - values` to a given product, may be you should look at `woocommerce` to get the idea or better `Oscar` a django-based ecommerce solution

Comment: give me an example please, how to use/show it in admin?